# Files do not appear in synchronized Folders

Tags: 11.10, ubuntu-one, sync

I use ubuntu one on ubuntu 11.10.

It seems that files that already exist in a folder that I synchronize are not taken in account, and are not uploaded in the cloud. But, once my folder is synchronized, if I create a file in this folder, it will be correctly uploaded.
Is there a reason to this ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-client/stable-2-0/+bug/869920) for ubuntu-one. A fix is committed but did not make it to 11.10. It will be fixed in 12.04.

Possible workarounds are restarting the ubuntu-one synch daemon from Ubuntu One preferences, or issuing the command

```
u1sdtool -q; killall ubuntuone-login; u1sdtool -c
```

A system reboot will also force the files to be synchronized. A final alternative is to move the contents elsewhere, add folder to sychronization and then move the contents back in.